# Computer freezes after local web content is accessed from another device

Tags: networking, crash

I use Ubuntu 16.04 in my computer. I run LAMP for development of PHP.

Whenever I access the web content from another device (Android browser) using IP address of my computer (192.168.0.104), my system freezes and the only thing I can do is restart the computer using power button.

When I run `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i error`, I see following log related to `iwlwifi`.

```
Oct 17 09:36:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1593.319976] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x82000000.
Oct 17 09:36:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1593.320142] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Oct 17 09:36:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1593.320382] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Oct 17 09:36:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1593.320485] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: type 0x00000000 cmd_id 0x1C
Oct 17 09:36:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1593.320490] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: seq 0x00EC service 0x0000001C
Oct 17 09:36:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1593.320495] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: timestamp 0x         D84254D
Oct 17 09:39:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1773.442395] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x82000000.
Oct 17 09:39:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1773.442614] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Oct 17 09:39:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1773.443015] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Oct 17 09:39:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1773.443197] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: type 0x00000000 cmd_id 0x1C
Oct 17 09:39:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1773.443211] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: seq 0x00BF service 0x0000001C
Oct 17 09:39:40 my-pc kernel: [ 1773.443225] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: timestamp 0x         AB24F0B
Oct 17 09:40:06 my-pc kernel: [ 1800.071197] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x82000000.
Oct 17 09:40:06 my-pc kernel: [ 1800.071354] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Oct 17 09:40:06 my-pc kernel: [ 1800.071550] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Oct 17 09:40:06 my-pc kernel: [ 1800.071624] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: type 0x00000000 cmd_id 0x1C
Oct 17 09:40:06 my-pc kernel: [ 1800.071628] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: seq 0x0070 service 0x0000001C
Oct 17 09:40:06 my-pc kernel: [ 1800.071633] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW Error notification: timestamp 0x         18C0BDF
```

I am not sure whether this is the actual cause of the problem.

I need to access the web content from Android device to debug website. But, due to the problem I am not able to do so.

I would like to know why this is happening and how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Have you seen [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1804841)? Also, what is the version output of the linux-firmware version from running `apt-cache show linux-firmware | head`?

Comment: Perhaps `dmesg | grep iwl` will provide additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was due to some bug in the Linux kernel.

Previously, I was using kernel of version `4.13.0-1012-oem`. I manually installed `4.15.0-65-lowlatency`. After the update, I am not facing the problem of system freezing.

If anyone is facing similar problem, I suggest you to install new version of Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems is a firmware error. you should try to update the router's firmware to the latest version. it will fix the problem. Otherwise, use another router.